# Want to clear some doubts regarding Garbage Collection ( AS3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package
{
     public class SomeClass
     {
       public var myBtn:Button ; 
       public function SomeClass()
       { 
         myBtn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFunction) ;
       }

       function clickFunction(e:Event){

        }

    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
 var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass(); // step 1 
 addChild(someClass); // step 2 
 removeChild(someClass); // step 3 
 someClass = null  // step 4
```

In the above, I want to completely destroy the someClass instance, so in step 4 it's been assigned null value.

Q1) Is step 4 ( assignment to null ) right way to destroy the instances ?

Q2) I referred : http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html using delete keyword for objects. But i don't think delete keyword can be used for class instances ? How to use it in this case then ?

Q3) What happens to myBtn eventListener in SomeClass. Should i add a removeEventListener manually, before destroying instances of SomeClass. Or would it get destroyed automatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Yes. (I assume the someClass variable is an instance variable)

2/ `delete` does not only remove the value of a variable, but even the variable definition. Since classes in AS3 are sealed in general, it won't work. I.e. `delete` should only be used on dynamically created members. Mainly "keys" of `Object` or `Dictionary` instances. But obviously you can remove the member definition of any class marked as `dynamic` using `delete`.

3/ Yes, always remove event listeners manually. You can create weakly referenced event listeners when registering the handler as a listener, but it's best to always make sure event listeners are removed manually, it's more readable, clear and fail-safe.

I tend to have a `destroy` method in all my classes, which can be called by the instance owner when it's cleaning up its references to a certain instance. This destroy method will unregister all event listeners, nullify instance members and do all kinds of cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

The SomeClass instance you created will get garbage-collected after there are no longer any references to it. By setting your variable to null, it removes that reference, and the SomeClass instance will get garbage-collected as long as there are no more references to it.

In the code above, you do not need to remove the event listener. When a SomeClass instance is collected, all of its member variables will be collected (unless they're referenced elsewhere). Because the event listener has been added *to the button*, it will be collected when the button is collected.

Something to note, however: if instead of `myBtn.addEventListener` you had used `stage.addEventListener`, the stage would retain a reference to your callback function and you could end up with a memory leak. Always remove event listeners that are assigned to objects that will still be around after you care about the listener.

Creynder's advice is good: remove event listeners as a matter of habit. It's only really necessary, however, when an event listener's dispatcher is going to hang around but you don't want the callback to stay in memory.